# Why is the Lagrange multiplier equal to zero if the constraint is slack?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Suppose we have a problem such as:

max f(x) subject to g(x) $\le$ b

where, g(x) is the constraint function

The Lagrange for such a problem could be constructed as follows,

L(x, $\lambda\ $) = f(x) + $\lambda\ $.[b - g(x)]

From complementary slackness, $\lambda$.[b - g(x)] = 0, if the function binds the b-g(x) = 0, if it doesn't 
 then $\lambda\ $ = 0, why is $\lambda$ = 0 if the constraint does not bind and is therefore slack?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this addresses your question, but if $x^*$ is a maximiser and $g(x^*) < b$, then $x^*$ is a solution to the unconstrained problem $\max f(x)$. You can always add/remove inactive constraints without changing the problem (at least locally).

Comment: Basically because of how the normal cone works. If you are exactly on the boundary of the constraint set in this context, then you know the normal cone is not empty or equal to $0$.